# How can I change the "using password" setting for logrotate to yes?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, logrotate, debian-stretch

I recently setup a DB using MariaDB and am now getting daily error messages from logrotate (see below). I am using a password for the root DB user. Per what I found online I setup the my.cnf file, but it has not changed anything. The error message states (using password: NO). Some of the posts I have seen online say "yes" instead. However, I cannot find any documentation online or in the MariaDB settings files where I can tell logrotate that it should be using a password.

**Error message:**

```
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate: mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost'
failed error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)' 
error: error running shared postrotate script for '/var/log/mysql/mysql.log /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log /var/log/mysql/error.log ' 
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/logrotate exited with return code 1
```

**/root/.my.cnf**

```
[mysqladmin]
password = "password"
user = root

[mysql]
password = "password"
user = root
```

I am running MariaDB 10.1.37 on Debian Stretch

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you provide separate user for mysqladmin and give it minimal privileges.  This may cut back on the vulnerability to hackers.

`mysqladmin` is like `mysql`, it uses arguments to decide what user, what host, and whether to ask for a password:

- `-p`  -- ask for a password dynamically (hard to use in a batch script)
- `-pMyPwd`  -- provide the password (not very secure)
- (neither of the above)  -- no password, or...

You can use `mysql_config_editor` to set up a password in a special way such that you do not need to include `-p`.

Comment: I understanding that for logging into mysql, but logrotate is a binary executable (/usr/sbin/logrotate) that is called daily by cron. It does not accept the -p argument. It appears that somewhere in either its settings or how it is being called, it is expecting to login without a password (the default for the root user in MariaDB). I just need to figure out how to instruct it to use the user and password in root's .my.cnf file. 

I have seen examples of error codes others have gotten where it prints "Using password: YES".